# Adding multiple vertical lines and scatterplot to cufflinks quantfig candlestick plot

Tags: python, time-series, plotly, candlestick-chart, cufflinks

I am trying to use cufflinks quantfigure to add more elements to the candlestick plot. I need guidance on 2 items.

1. Add multiple horizontal lines, in different color, at once. I am able to add multiple lines of predefined color or single line of custom color but I am not able to add multiple lines of custom color

```
qf=cf.QuantFig(data,title='Apple Quant Figure',legend='top',name='GS')
qf.add_shapes(hline =[225,275]) # plots same red color lines at to locations 
qf.add_shapes(hline = dict(y=250,color='blue',width=3, dash='dashdot')) #plots single custom line at the location

qf.add_shapes(hline = [dict(y=300,color='blue',width=3, dash='dashdot'),
                       dict(y=250,color='blue',width=3, dash='dashdot')]) #does not work

qf.add_shapes(hline = dict(y=[200,300],color='blue',width=3, dash='dashdot')) #does not work
```

Trying to add multiple lines of custom type (color and line style) does not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxTqg.png)

2. How add scatter plot on the candlestick plot. I am trying to plot something like this using cufflinks:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCxBk.png)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, draws 2 horizontal and 2 vertical lines to get a rectangle:

```
qf.add_shapes(hline=[{'x0': '2021-02-17 00:00:00', 'x1': '2021-02-27 00:00:00', 'y': 40000, 'color': 'orange'}])
qf.add_shapes(hline=[{'x0': '2021-02-17 00:00:00', 'x1': '2021-02-27 00:00:00', 'y': 41000, 'color': 'blue'}])
qf.add_shapes(vline=[{'x': '2021-02-17 00:00:00', 'y0': 40000, 'y1': 41000, 'color': 'orange'}])
qf.add_shapes(vline=[{'x': '2021-02-27 00:00:00', 'y0': 40000, 'y1': 41000, 'color': 'blue'}])
```